# what is return number in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

my question is what return -1 does in this code and overall?
like when you return number in a function what exactly it does?

```
def linearSearch(array, n, x):

    # Going through array sequencially
    for i in range(0, n):
        if (array[i] == x):
            return i
    return -1


array = [2, 4, 0, 1, 9]
x = 1
n = len(array)
result = linearSearch(array, n, x)
if(result == -1):
    print("Element not found")
else:
    print("Element found at index: ", result)
```

Comment: The function is returning `-1` to signal that the searched element was not fund, otherwise it returns the index where it was found.

Comment: It literally returns this number. Say, after `result = linearSearch([], 0, 5)`, `result` will be `-1`

Comment: If you want to understand "return", it should be covered in any tutorial. Think of it as the output of the function, output which other parts of the code can use.

Comment: It is just a flag, if you replace the various `-1` with `"potato"` it will work identically

Comment: ``return`` is a pretty fundamental statement and any tutorial should have introduced you to it. Do you know what it means to return something other than a number?

Comment: `-1` is easily distinguishable from a "valid" index (which ranges from `0` to `len(array) - 1`). However, `-1` can be *used* as an index, in which case it is treated as an offset from the end of the array, rather than the beginning. As such, it's not really a good choice as a sentinel, because it could accidentally be used an index unless you explicitly check. `None` is better, because it cannot silently be used as an index.

Answer (score 0):

Return is a statement to terminate a function. It is the value that should be given to a variable when called. It is the value that must be "returned" when the function is overall executed. Let us say, in your program we wrote a statement:

> j=linearSearch([1,2,3,4],3,2)

Then the function is getting called. The function is executed and according to your code it will become:

```
for i in range(0,3):
    if [1,2,3,4][i]==2:
        return i
    return -1
```

Here, the condition gets satisfied for i=1 because at index 1, 2 is present. So the return value i.e. j's is 1 and the function gets terminated. If we take another example:

> j=linearSearch ([1,2,3,4],3,5)

Then the code would be:

```
for i in range(0,3):
    if [1,2,3,4][i]==5:
        return i
    return -1
```

Here, the condition never gets satisfied and the loop is completed. Now the return value i.e. j's value is -1